# Almost all files are created by root user in my Docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.10.5-alpine

ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN adduser -D appuser

USER appuser

WORKDIR /home/appuser/

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN python -m pip install --user --no-cache-dir --disable-pip-version-check --requirement requirements.txt

COPY . .

ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

So I create a user called `appuser` and switch to it as soon as I can before copying anything (I've checked both user and its home folder is created).

But when I browse the filesystem of my image:

```
~ $ ls -l
total 156
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           335 Jul 28 10:57 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r--    1 appuser  appuser     131072 Jul 28 12:28 db.sqlite3
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           150 Jul 28 11:37 entrypoint.sh
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root           685 Jul 28 10:04 manage.py
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jul 28 10:56 project
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            41 Jul 28 11:56 requirements.txt
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root          4096 Jul 28 11:50 static
drwxr-xr-x    5 root     root          4096 Jul 28 10:05 venv
```

... almost everything belongs to `root` user and this gives me several `permission denied` errors.

What is my mistake because I assume Docker shouldn't operate under `root` when I've switched the user?

I know I can add `RUN mkdir ~/static` to the Dockerfile and get over it, but then what [the documentation says](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#user) about `USER` command doesn't make sense to me:

> The USER instruction sets the user name (or UID) and optionally the user group (or GID) to use as the default user and group for the remainder of the current stage.

Comment: That file ownership looks pretty much perfect to me: your user can read and write the database file, but is prevented from (accidentally or otherwise) modifying the application code.

Comment: @DavidMaze One of the issues I'm facing right now is the ```collectstatic``` management command of Django fails to execute because the ```static``` folder belongs to ```root``` and not the ```appuser```

Comment: That seems like a good thing to `RUN` in your Dockerfile, before you switch to a non-root `USER`.  (You also don't want your application accidentally modifying its static assets.)

Comment: @DavidMaze I'm not sure that can be done. The ```static``` folder is copied to the image as part of ```COPY . .``` command so I have to shift almost everything up and run ```USER``` command at the **end** of Dockerfile???

Comment: Running `USER` as the last step makes sense to me.

Comment: @DavidMaze You clearly don't know the answer to my question so you keep talking about what **you** think is good or makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the optional flag `--chown=<user>:<group>` with either the `ADD` or `COPY` commands.

For example:

```bash
COPY --chown=appuser:appuser . .
```

[docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy)

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works but I still don't know why ```USER``` command is not working as I think it should.